# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function addData()

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, mage, adminhtml

I am using Magento v1.8 CE and I am having an issue when trying to access any exportation/importation functionality from the Dataflow - Profiles section within System > Export/Import. The error reads:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addData() on a non-object in /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Gui/Edit/Tabs.php on line 49

I have found related issues [here](http://magentotutorial.org/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray-on-a-non-object/) but I would prefer not to mess with core Mage code. According to this article: the most probable cause for this kind of error may appear as a result of an out-dated Mage_Core_Adminhtml package, or package is upgraded but old code is cached by compiler.

I have not upgraded any packages, however I do have a local version of the site on another server which works fine. It could be slight differences between the 2 servers but I can't be sure. Can someone help me out? Or explain the purpose of the Mage "Adminhtml" module so I can gain a better understanding of where it is going wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 48 of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Gui/Edit/Tabs.php`.
There you should see

```
$wizardBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_gui_edit_tab_wizard');
```

You should check if you have that file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Gui/Edit/Tab/Wizard.php`.
If you have the file above, verify what's `$this->getLayout()` by using the methods is_object and get_class. Also check for any modules from app/code/local or app/code/community that override the class from the second file above.

As a last resort go into the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php file and edit the getGroupedClassName method around line 1213 and before `return $className` add a new row with `Mage::log($className, null, 'block_classes.log');`.
Now you should have a log in var/log/block_classes.log and see what class Magento is trying to initialize before it throws that error.

Comment: Thanks Emi, the problem was the missing Wizard.php file, for some reason it existed on my local but not on the other testing server, it must have been skipped during a transfer. I really appreciate the help.